# How do I make a form appear with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I Have a form 2 radio choices, a and b, when the form is submited i want another form, a form for a and one for b, to go from display:none to display:block depending on the choice. here's what i have.

```
<script>
    function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["choice"]["choose one"].value;
        if (x == "A") {
            document.getElementById("a").style.display = "block";
            }
        else {
            document.getElementById("b").style.display = "block";
            }
        }   
</script>
```

and later in html.

```
<form action="form.php" method="get" name="choice">
                    0000:<br>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="choose one" value="A">
                        A
                    </label><br>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="choose one" value="B">
                        B
                    </label><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Sub">
                </form>

<form id="a">
</form>

<form id="b">
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please outline exactly what the problem is you are facing. You can find out more on how to ask good questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

1. You need to call `validateForm()` on click of submit button
2. Hide the forms initially, on choosing the form, the forms will get displayed

```html
<script>
  function validateForm() {

    var x = document.forms["choice"]["choose one"].value;
    if (x == "A") {
      document.getElementById("a").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("b").style.display = "none";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("b").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("a").style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>


<form method="get" name="choice">
  0000:<br>
  <label>
      <input type="radio" name="choose one" value="A">
                        A
  </label><br>
  <label>
      <input type="radio" name="choose one" value="B">
                        B
  </label><br>
  <input type="button" value="Sub" onclick="validateForm()">
</form>

<form id="a" style="display:none">
  form a
</form>

<form id="b" style="display:none">
  form b
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an `onchange` event and set both forms to `display:none` on start:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("change", (evt) => validateForm(evt))
})

function validateForm(e) {
  let a = document.getElementById("a")
  let b = document.getElementById("b")

  a.style.display = b.style.display = "none"

  if (e.target.value == "A") {
    a.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    b.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#a,
#b {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<form action="form.php" method="get" name="choice">
  0000:<br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="choose one" value="A">
     A
  </label><br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="choose one" value="B">
    B
   </label><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Sub">
</form>

<form id="a">
  Form A
</form>

<form id="b">
  Form B
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form , it reloads the page . So you can't show a form after the first form is submitted, in the default case.

So you either need to submit the form using AJAX, or include the other two forms in the first form (change them to `<div>` tags, and put them inside the first form). Change the submit button to just a `<button>` element with an `onclick` method, to show the second part of the form, and it should also show the real submit button.
You may want to disable submitting the form when the user presses `enter` while typing in any fields, and disable submitting with the soft keyboard on mobile.
It should be possible to find with Google how to do each of these.